# app cache doesn't work in the android device (works well on the chrome browser)

Tags: android, web-applications, application-cache

I'm trying to use app cache to approve the performance.

I have been guided in various sites. (ex. http://xguru.net/621 ... )

make cache.man file, set mime-type as text/cache-manifest.

Problem is...

it works well at the Google chrome browser, but does not work in my android phone.

I tested at ICS and Gingerbread.

This is manifest file .

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# manifest version v0.1 

CACHE:
./programs.png
./video.png

NETWORK:
*
```

and then, I set my webview like this.

```
getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
```

(I changed the cacheMode to LOAD_NORMAL, NO_CACHE, but it's not different.)

To see the cache state, I use this site.
http://jonathanstark.com/blog/2009/09/27/debugging-html-5-offline-application-cache/

```
var cacheStatusValues = [];
cacheStatusValues[0] = 'uncached';
cacheStatusValues[1] = 'idle';
cacheStatusValues[2] = 'checking';
cacheStatusValues[3] = 'downloading';
cacheStatusValues[4] = 'updateready';
cacheStatusValues[5] = 'obsolete';

var cache = window.applicationCache;
cache.addEventListener('cached', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('checking', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('downloading', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('error', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('noupdate', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('obsolete', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('progress', logEvent, false);
cache.addEventListener('updateready', logEvent, false);

function logEvent(e) {
    var online, status, type, message;
    online = (navigator.onLine) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    status = cacheStatusValues[cache.status];
    type = e.type;
    message = 'online: ' + online;
    message+= ', event: ' + type;
    message+= ', status: ' + status;
    if (type == 'error' && navigator.onLine) {
        message+= ' (prolly a syntax error in manifest)';
    }
    console.log(message);
}

window.applicationCache.addEventListener(
    'updateready',
    function(){
        window.applicationCache.swapCache();
        console.log('swap cache has been called');
    },
    false
);
```

Lastly, This is the log I see on my android phone.

```
[cache Resource] app cache support! 
[cache Resource] DOWNLOADING 
[cache Resource] event online: yes, event: checking, status: uncached 
[cache Resource] event online: yes, event: downloading, status: uncached 
[cache Resource] event online: yes, event: progress, status: uncached 
[cache Resource] event online: yes, event: progress, status: uncached 
[cache Resource] event online: yes, event: error, status: uncached (prolly a syntax error in manifest)
```

Images are downloaded but we get the error at last line. 
So it is always in a uncached.

I guess the problem is on the webview setting or android application.
But i cannot handle it.

give me a tip to use app cache.. plz...

Comment: got the same failure... removed all entries in the manifest so it should just cache the master page: checking, downloading, error.

Answer (score 2):

Indirectly the answer linked by yugidroid led me to the right line. The blog which is linked in the answer shows what to do:

```
    String appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
```

I removed those lines again for testing: same error - readded: no error!